# Ansible. How to choose N hosts from group

Tags: ansible

Assume that a group has 10 hosts.
How to run playbook on N hosts from 10. N is arbitrary value from 1 to 10.
Example:

```
- hosts: groups['group_name'][1:3] it works.
```

But it doesn't work if instead of 3 I use variable, like this

```
- hosts: groups['group_name'][1:N]
```

It could be random N, first N, last N what ever.

Thank you.

Comment: I've answered similar question [here]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/38264504/2795592). You can form any group dynamically. You can use `when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) < my_N_var` as condition.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as well. The same issue.  If when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) < 2 - it works.  If my_N_var - it doesn't

Comment: How do you pass your variable into the playbook? have you tried `-e my_N_var=3`?

Comment: yes. And also tried to reassign like vars: new_var: my_N_var. when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) < new_var

Comment: ansible version 1.9.4. At home I will try it with latest ansible.

Comment: ansible 2.1.0 when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) < my_N_var doesn't work :( The same as ansible 1.9.4

Comment: I use -e my_N_var=2 to pass variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work absolutely fine in ansible 2.1:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=limited_selection
      when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) < max_index | int

- hosts: limited_selection
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="I'm in the limited selection group!"
```

Exec like this: `ansible-playbook -e max_index=3 playbook.yml` or define `max_index` somewhere else.